# unable to create sharded mongo db on localhost

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to create simple mongo db cluster on localhost (as a POC) with MongoDB 4.0.1 Community.
This cluster consists from one shard and single member replica set. I was following this tutorial but i got stuck https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/

As first step i have started mongod as config server with following configuration:

```
sharding:
  clusterRole: configsvr
replication:
  replSetName: configServerTestReplicaSet
net:
  bindIp: localhost
```

Then i have connected to this config server and initialised replica set via

```
rs.initiate()
```

Afterwards i moved to shard replica set with configuration:

```
sharding:
  clusterRole: shardsvr
replication:
  replSetName: shardServerReplicaSet
net:
  bindIp: localhost
```

Than again i have connected to this instance and ran

```
rs.initiate()
```

Next step was to connect mongos to sharded cluster.
So i started mongos with following configuration:

```
sharding:
  configDB: configServerTestReplicaSet/localhost:27019
net:
  bindIp: localhost
```

When i start mongos i see following log

```
2018-09-04T08:59:00.378+0200 I NETWORK  [mongosMain] waiting for connections on port 27017
```

So i connect to mongos via

```
mongo.exe --host localhost --port 27017
```

As next step i try to add shard to cluster

```
sh.addShard( "localhost:27017")
```

which results in following error:

```
sh.addShard( "localhost:27018")
{
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "no such command: 'addShard'",
        "code" : 59,
        "codeName" : "CommandNotFound"
}
```

[no such command add shard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XSpg.png)

From help it is clear that addShard is valid command and i have tried various syntax combinations with double/single quotes spaces and so on...

What am I doing wrong? Have I missed something during configuration?

Thanks for your suggestions...

Comment: The `sh.addShard()` command is only available if you are connected to a `mongos` instance. I suspect you may have accidentally connected to one of the shard servers. If you are connected to `mongos` your `mongo` shell prompt should be `mongos>` by default. You can also run the `mongo` shell command `db.isMaster().msg`, which should return `isdbgrid` if you are connected to `mongos` (or no result if you aren't). If you are definitely connected to a `mongos` and `sh.addShard()` is returning "no such command", please edit your question to include the output of `version()` and `db.isMaster()`.

Comment: @Stennie thank you for your comment. You made me realise that i have connected to mongo service which was running on the same port on my machine... i was able to connect to mongos and add a shard as soon as i had shut down that service...